# XQuery: Compare one value to multiple values like SQL "in" command

Tags: operators, xquery

I need to compare one value to multiple other values (a query resulting in more than one element), therefore, if a value is included in some other values. In SQL there's the "IN" operator for that, but what about XQuery? 
Thanks for any hint :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XQuery `=` operator behaves exactly as you describe:

```
3 = (1,2,3,4,5)
```

is `true`.

The `eq` operator is the version for comparing single values.

However if you are looking for whether a node `$node` is in a particular list of nodes `$sequence`, then you want

```
some $x in $sequence satisfies $x is $node
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let $values := ('1', '2', '3')
for $row in $table
where $row/value = $values
return $row
```

Or you could do this if you inlined it:

```
for $row in $table
where $row/value = ('1', '2', '3')
return $row
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've seen you replied before Oliver and your answer is correct too, yet I found Olivers post easier to understand, so I selected Oliver's post as answer. Hope you don't mind!